# Logging ping results

Tags: windows, logging, cmd, ping

I am tracking multiple circuits.  I do this task by pinging from a machine across to a distant IP address.  I have more recently added the logging feature with help from this site, but the logs are growing too fast and it is slowing down the database that is pulling information from the text file.  Is it possible to only log values certain values.  Starting with those values that timeout.
Thanks in advance

Here is a small section of what is produced in the log file.  I only want to keep when the session says Timed Out.

Thu 01/15/2015 -  8:16:10.27 - 74.125.230.244 - rtt[284]

Thu 01/15/2015 -  8:16:12.60 - 74.125.230.244 - rtt[154]

Thu 01/15/2015 -  8:16:14.91 - 74.125.230.244 - rtt[154]

Thu 01/15/2015 -  8:16:21.65 - 74.125.230.244 - rtt[Timed Out]

Thu 01/15/2015 -  8:16:23.74 - 74.125.230.244 - rtt[Timed Out]

Thu 01/15/2015 -  8:16:29.36 - 74.125.230.244 - rtt[Timed Out]

Thu 01/15/2015 -  8:16:31.86 - 74.125.230.244 - rtt[Timed Out]

Thu 01/15/2015 -  8:16:35.36 - 74.125.230.244 - rtt[Timed Out]

Thu 01/15/2015 -  8:16:40.36 - 74.125.230.244 - rtt[Timed Out]

Thu 01/15/2015 -  8:16:45.36 - 74.125.230.244 - rtt[Timed Out]

Thu 01/15/2015 -  8:16:48.36 - 74.125.230.244 - rtt[Timed Out]

Thu 01/15/2015 -  8:16:54.35 - 74.125.230.244 - rtt[Timed Out]

Thu 01/15/2015 -  8:16:56.80 - 74.125.230.244 - rtt[287]

Thu 01/15/2015 -  8:16:59.18 - 74.125.230.244 - rtt[249]

```
@echo off
TITLE = Circuit 1
mode 40,20
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

rem Get address from command line
set "address=74.125.230.244"
if not defined address set "address=127.0.0.1"

rem Configure levels and colors 
rem The format is initialValue:color in value descending format
set "levels=9000:4F 178:E0 146:2F 0:E0"

rem infinite loop
for /l %%i in () do (
    rem retrieve information from ping command
    set "rtt=Timed Out"
    set "ttl=?"
    for /f "tokens=3,4 delims==^<" %%a in (
        'ping -n 1 "%address%" ^| find "TTL="'
    ) do for /f "tokens=1 delims=m" %%c in ("%%a") do (
        set /a "rtt=%%c"
        set "ttl=%%b"
    )

    rem retrieve color
    set "color="
    for %%z in (%levels%) do for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ("%%z") do (
        if not defined color if !rtt! geq %%a set "color=%%b"
    )

    rem show information
    if defined color color !color!
    echo(!time! - %address% - rtt[!rtt!]

    rem save to log
    for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=.:-/ " %%a in ("!date!") do (
        >> "%%b-%%c-%%d_%%a_circuit1.txt" echo(!date! - !time! - %address% - rtt[!rtt!]
    )

    rem wait and repeat the process
    ping -n 3 localhost >nul 2>nul 
)
```

Comment: Quite likely. Now please reveal the secret information. Exemplify the results that you want to log by `edit`ing your question.

Comment: @Magoo  I am not sure what you need?  The question is can I log just the timeout response.

Comment: **You** are aware of the lines in the logfile that you want to retain, and those that you want to discard. Show us examples of lines you want to retain and those you want to discard. Replace sensitive information with generics (like a series of xs) if necessary. We can't read your mind.

Comment: I have added a section of what is produced in the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, all you need to do is gate the `for` that is executing the `echo` to the log:

```
....
echo(!time! - %address% - rtt[!rtt!]

rem save to log
if "!rtt!"=="Timed Out" for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=.:-/ " %%a in ("!date!") do (
    >> "%%b-%%c-%%d_%%a_circuit1.txt" echo(!date! - !time! - %address% - rtt[!rtt!]
)
....
```